# PHP - How to check if value already exist in array?

Tags: php, arrays

Here is how i make my array:

```
if($Love != " "){
    $LoveArray['Couple'] = $Love;
}
```

The lines above are in while loop. When i do `print_r($LoveArray);` i receive the following output:

> Array ( [Couple] => 5726 ) Array ( [Couple] => 3421 ) Array ( [Couple]
>   => 3421 ) Array ( [Couple] => 3421 ) Array ( [Couple] => 2213 ) Array ( [Couple] => 2213 ) Array ( [Couple] => 5339 ) Array ( [Couple] =>
>   5339 ) Array ( [Couple] => 3910 ) Array ( [Couple] => 3910 ) Array (
>   [Couple] => 3910 ) Array ( [Couple] => 3910 ) Array ( [Couple] => 3910
>   ) Array ( [Couple] => 3910 ) Array ( [Couple] => 3910 ) Array (
>   [Couple] => 3910 ) Array ( [Couple] => 3421 ) Array ( [Couple] => 5726
>   ) Array ( [Couple] => 2213 ) Array ( [Couple] => 2213 ) Array (
>   [Couple] => 2213 ) Array ( [Couple] => 2213 ) Array ( [Couple] => 2213
>   ) Array ( [Couple] => 2213 ) Array ( [Couple] => 2213 ) Array (
>   [Couple] => 2213 ) Array ( [Couple] => 2213 ) Array ( [Couple] => 2213
>   ) Array ( [Couple] => 2213 ) Array ( [Couple] => 2213 ) Array (
>   [Couple] => 6327 ) Array ( [Couple] => 6327 ) Array ( [Couple] => 3910
>   ) Array ( [Couple] => 3910 ) Array ( [Couple] => 3910 ) Array (
>   [Couple] => 3910 ) Array ( [Couple] => 3910 ) Array ( [Couple] => 3910
>   ) Array ( [Couple] => 3910 ) Array ( [Couple] => 3910 ) Array (
>   [Couple] => 3910 ) Array ( [Couple] => 5339 ) Array ( [Couple] => 5339
>   ) Array ( [Couple] => 6327 ) Array ( [Couple] => 6327 ) Array (
>   [Couple] => 6327 ) Array ( [Couple] => 6327 ) Array ( [Couple] => 6327
>   )

The array above could be represented as:

```
<?php

    $array  = [
        ["Couple" => 5726],

        ["Couple" => 3421],
        ["Couple" => 3421],
        ["Couple" => 3421],

        ["Couple" => 2213],
        ["Couple" => 2213],

        ["Couple" => 5339],
        ["Couple" => 5339],

        ["Couple" => 3910],
        ["Couple" => 3910],
        ["Couple" => 3910],
        ["Couple" => 3910],
        ["Couple" => 3910],
        ["Couple" => 3910],
        ["Couple" => 3910],

        ["Couple" => 3910],
        ["Couple" => 3421],
        ["Couple" => 5726],

        ["Couple" => 2213],
        ["Couple" => 2213],
        ["Couple" => 2213],
        ["Couple" => 2213],
        ["Couple" => 2213],
        ["Couple" => 2213],
        ["Couple" => 2213],
        ["Couple" => 2213],
        ["Couple" => 2213],
        ["Couple" => 2213],
        ["Couple" => 2213],
        ["Couple" => 2213],

        ["Couple" => 6327],
        ["Couple" => 6327],

        ["Couple" => 3910],
        ["Couple" => 3910],
        ["Couple" => 3910],
        ["Couple" => 3910],
        ["Couple" => 3910],
        ["Couple" => 3910],
        ["Couple" => 3910],
        ["Couple" => 3910],
        ["Couple" => 3910],

        ["Couple" => 5339],
        ["Couple" => 5339],

        ["Couple" => 6327],
        ["Couple" => 6327],
        ["Couple" => 6327],
        ["Couple" => 6327],
        ["Couple" => 6327],
    ];
```

As you can see there are values which are repeating, one of them is `5726`.

How can i check if `5726` is already in `$LoveEvent['Couple']` and if it is there to not insert another in this array ?

Kind regards.

Comment: You can store all ids in array, without subarrays and use `in_array`

Comment: Already checked `in_array()` and it seems to be not working for me.

Comment: Because you have subarrays here.

Comment: I need the subarrays.

Comment: @TonyStark. Provide with a solution. Share your thoughts on that after you implement it over to your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check the value exist in an array the use of in_array() is preferred.

But as of now you need to check it for the multidimensional array so that you can use the in_array() in a recursive way so that it will be useful for finding the value is present in an array or not.

```
<?php
function check_array_value($to_find, $array_values, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($array_values as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $to_find : $item == $to_find) || (is_array($item) && check_array_value($to_find, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
?>
```

Usage of this function can be done like this.

```
$array_values = array(array("Name", "Apple"), array("Orange", "IOS"));
echo check_array_value("IOS", $array_values) ? 'found' : 'not found';
```

If the `IOS` is present in the array it will return as `found` or else it will return `not found`.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this:

```
foreach($LoveArray as $value){
    if($value['Couple'] != $Love){
        $LoveArray['Couple'] = $Love;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($Love != " ") {
    if (!in_array($Love, array_column($LoveArray, 'Couple'))) {
        $LoveArray['Couple'] = $Love;
        $finalArray[] = $LoveArray; //adding the new element should also be here
    }
}
```

Requires
(PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7)
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

```
$arr = ['orange', 'apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'banana'];
$finalArray = [];

foreach ($arr as $item) {
    if (!in_array($item, array_column($finalArray, 'Couple'))) {
        $finalArray[] = ['Couple' => $item];
    }
}

print_r($finalArray);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Couple] => orange
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Couple] => apple
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Couple] => banana
        )

)
```

Comment: This is not working. It is again inserting duplicate results.

Comment: Could paste a bit more of your snippet, there must be something like $someOtherArray[] = $LoveArray; and the one you are printing is $someOtherArray, am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple, `foreach`-based Solution you might wanna try out. And by the way, you may [Quick-Test it here](https://eval.in/649596):

```
<?php
    $array      = [
            ["Couple" => 5726],
            ["Couple" => 3421],
            ["Couple" => 3421],
            ["Couple" => 3421],
            ["Couple" => 2213],
            ["Couple" => 2213],
            ["Couple" => 5339],
            ["Couple" => 5339],
            ["Couple" => 3910],
            ["Couple" => 3910],
            ["Couple" => 3910],
            ["Couple" => 3910],
            ["Couple" => 3910],
            ["Couple" => 3910],
            ["Couple" => 3910],
            ["Couple" => 3910],
            ["Couple" => 3421],
            ["Couple" => 5726],
            ["Couple" => 2213],
            ["Couple" => 2213],
            ["Couple" => 2213],
            ["Couple" => 2213],
            ["Couple" => 2213],
            ["Couple" => 2213],
            ["Couple" => 2213],
            ["Couple" => 2213],
            ["Couple" => 2213],
            ["Couple" => 2213],
            ["Couple" => 2213],
            ["Couple" => 2213],
            ["Couple" => 6327],
            ["Couple" => 6327],
            ["Couple" => 3910],
            ["Couple" => 3910],
            ["Couple" => 3910],
            ["Couple" => 3910],
            ["Couple" => 3910],
            ["Couple" => 3910],
            ["Couple" => 3910],
            ["Couple" => 3910],
            ["Couple" => 3910],
            ["Couple" => 5339],
            ["Couple" => 5339],
            ["Couple" => 6327],
            ["Couple" => 6327],
            ["Couple" => 6327],
            ["Couple" => 6327],
            ["Couple" => 6327],
        ];

        $arrFinal   = [];

        foreach($array as $iKey=>$arrCouple){
            if(!in_array($arrCouple, $arrFinal)){
                $arrFinal[] = $arrCouple;
            }else{
                // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO
                // IN THE CASE THE DATA DOES ALREADY EXIST...
                // THIS WOULD BE UP TO YOU...
            }
        }

        var_dump($arrFinal);
```

The `var_dump($arrFinal);` Yields:

```
        array (size=6)
          0 =>
            array (size=1)
              'Couple' => int 5726
          1 =>
            array (size=1)
              'Couple' => int 3421
          2 =>
            array (size=1)
              'Couple' => int 2213
          3 =>
            array (size=1)
              'Couple' => int 5339
          4 =>
            array (size=1)
              'Couple' => int 3910
          5 =>
            array (size=1)
              'Couple' => int 6327
```